# Make "Unreachable code detected" compilation warning instead of error in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, when there is unreachable code, the compiler generates by default error:

```
error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.
```

I can avoid it by using compiler option `allowUnreachableCode` to `true` but can I change it somehow to warning?

I would still prefer to know about unreachable code. During development and debugging I sometimes use `if (false)` to temporarily remove some functionality, which is better than commenting the code out especially when the code itself contains comments.

In C#, unreachable code generates warning (which I can treat as error by other option), which seems to me better way to handle it.

Comment: Even when the compiler finds errors it will still emit the js result, unless you are using the `--noEmitOnError` flag. So, you can look at the errors as warnings

Comment: @NitzanTomer good point. And despite of `webpack: Failed to compile.` message it seems the error does not stop webpack to build the bundle

Comment: could you set a global variable alwaysFalse=false; and in typescript declare the var (thereby making Typescript compiler unaware that it is always false) and then do if (alwaysFalse) instead if (false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer as of the time of writing is "no", it cannot be made into a warning; as you said, it is either "error" or "nothing".  [This Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13408) exists to allow errors to be configured into warnings, which would allow this to be made into a warning.  Hopefully it will get implemented soon.

Answer (score 10):

In the particular case of temporarily removing functionality (which I think is the main case where one would *want* to have unreachable code), writing

```
if( <any>false ) {
  // unused code goes here
}
```

will prevent the TypeScript compiler from complaining, *and* give the runtime ECMAScript implementation a pretty good chance of optimizing the code away.

Alternatively,

```
if( 0 ) {
  // unused code goes here
}
```

will be accepted by the TypeScript language, but will still trigger an "unexpected constant condition" warning from `tslint`.

Comment: This is a bad answer.  The question asked whether it could be a WARNING, not whether the error could be avoided completely.

Comment: @Jez: The second proposal will create a linter warning.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, thanks to this post, I was able to find the first piece of the puzzle (`allowUnreachableCode` to `true`), here is the other piece:

- https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unreachable
- [image: no-unreachable: warn]