# VS Code eslint underlining wrong errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint

**Problem**

eslint is underlining errors incorrectly in my React Native files.

Here is one example of a file that has incorrect errors.  In this example it is saying `cannot find name source` even though that is an accepted prop by `Image` in React Native.

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

[image: Screen]
[image: Error]

Comment: This should help you figure this out. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854634/error-ts7027-unreachable-code-detected-in-angular2-typescript-service-class and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996455/error-ts7027-unreachable-code-detected-typescript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407742/make-unreachable-code-detected-compilation-warning-instead-of-error-in-typescr

Comment: What is the language mode for the file extension you have open? If you look in the bottom-right corner what language/framework is listed? You can also change the language mode by clicking that button or via the command palette.